# Get illegal characters with data annotations validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, data-annotations

I am using data annotation to detect illegal characters in web page textbox.

```
[RegularExpression(Constants.LegalName, ErrorMessage = "Full name is invalid.")]
public string FullName {
    get;
    set;
}

const string LegalName= @"^[a-zA-Z '-.]*$";
```

I validate the fields with the following code

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(
    inputFieldValue, 
    new ValidationContext(inputFieldValue, null, null), 
    result, 
    true);
```

if there is any illegal characters detected, the result will have an error string with "Full name is invalid."

How do I get a list of illegal characters typed into the field? The string inputFieldValue will have what the user typed into the field. How can I get a list of all illegal characters with the reg express like  `@"^[a-zA-Z '-.]*$";`

Thanks.

Comment: Why not mention what characters are valid in the message rather than trying to find and put the invalid ones in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you can get it with `TryValidateObject`. You have to find them separately:

```
const string ValidCharPattern = @"[a-zA-Z '-.]";

const string LegalName= @"^" + ValidCharPattern + @"*$";


var invalidChars = Regex
    .Replace(
        input: inputFieldValue,
        pattern: ValidCharPattern,
        replacement: String.Empty)
    .Distinct();
```